# Viewing tasks of multiple users in Eclipse JBPM Human Task Viewer

Tags: eclipse, jbpm

Is there a way to view tasks assign to all or multiple users in JBPM Human Task View in Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The human task server has the concept of an administrator, and jBPM5 automatically assigns a user "Administrator" as the administrator of tasks.  Querying tasks as administrator should give you more power than just querying your own tasks.